# Where "contains" with alias column

Tags: sql

In case, I must use "CONTAINS" in where statement. How can I use it with alias column?

This following example is simple case for easy understanding. In real,
my statement is more complex, what I must use "CONTAINS" in where statement. So, please don't tell me use another solution instead of using "CONTAINS". Thanks

```
Select * from users where contains (*, @user_input)
```

In db, gender is stored with 1 is Male, 0 is Female. But, user only see Male, and Female on UI.

If user inputs 1 (or 0), the result SHOULD NOT contain users with Male (or Female).

If I convert 1 to Male or 0 to Female before execute SQL, it will failed in case the other columns need search containing 1. For example: (Name, Gender, Note) = ("David", 1, 1)

I try to create alias column

```
select *
from(
      Select *, (case when GENDER = 1 then 'Male' when GENDER = 0 then 'Female' end) alias_gender
    )
where contains(*, @user_input)
```

But, I have an error, because the contains only works when contains in subquery

How can I deal with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Won't this still throw up incorrect results if any of your other columns contain the value 'Male' or 'Female'?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `contains()` is not standard SQL

Comment: @Chitharanjan Das: this work as design. If other columns contains "Male" or "Female", the result will show them

Comment: DBMS I'm working is SAP Hana-DB